# Angular 5 Nested Routing

Tags: angular5, angular4-router

Here is my code

```html
<ul>
  <li> <a routerLink="/dashboard">Dashboard</a></li>
  <li> <a routerLink="/price">Price</a> </li>  
</ul>
```

and the routing part is

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent },
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' },
  {
      path: 'price/:priceId',
      component: PriceComponent,
      children: [
        {path: '', redirectTo:'kpi', pathMatch: 'full'}, 
        {path: 'kpi', component: DashboardComponent}, 
        {path: 'data', component: DashboardComponent}, 
      ]
    }
];
```

here is the error that I got

ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'price'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'price'

What is my mistake and how can I solve this. I want to do the nesting routing. on click on `<li> <a routerLink="/price">Price</a> </li>`. I want to open the http://localhost:4200/price/kpi default first child in nesting routing.

Comment: You'll need to add routes for when there is no `priceId`

Comment: How can i add this @DanielWStrimpel

Comment: You'll have routes like `price/:priceId/kpi` and `price/kpi`, correct?

Comment: My routes are /price/kpi and /price/data @DanielWStrimpel

Comment: Ok. So you don't want the `:priceId` parameter on your routes then?

Comment: data and kpi are used as priceId

Comment: That isn't how the URLs work. You can just remove the `/:priceId` then

Comment: works thanks @DanielWStrimpel